# Can you slice a numpy 2D array with start and stop rules not at an index but at values greater than 1?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice

I have turned a geotiff LiDAR elevation surface into a numpy array by the below code:

`example_array = np.array(geotiff_surface)`

The array is hundreds of values by hundreds of values but could be simplified into an example below:

```
example_array = [[ 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
                 [ 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
                 [ 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0]
                 [ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0]
                 [ 0, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

with the help of others I am trying to slice the 2D array to increase the values at specific locations by 1000 with the code below:

```
sub_array = example_array[1:-1, 1:-1]
sub_array = [sub_array > 1] += 1000
```

in hopes to get the below correct example array:

```
correct_example_array = [[ 0,  0,    0,    1,    1,   0, 0, 0]
                         [ 0,  0,    2,   1002, 1002, 2, 0, 0]
                         [ 0,  3,   1003, 1003,  3,   0, 0, 0]
                         [ 4, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 4, 0, 0]
                         [ 0,  0,    0,    5,    5,   0, 0, 0]]
```

when in reality what my current code gives me is this array:

```
  incorrect_example_array = [[ 0,  0,    0,    1,    1,    0,   0, 0]
                             [ 0,  0,   1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 0, 0]
                             [ 0, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003,  0,   0, 0]
                             [ 4, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 0, 0]
                             [ 0,   0,    0,    5,    5,    0,  0, 0]]
```

Is there a way to get the slice to understand to skip the zeros in the lists and start slicing [1:-1] within values greater than 1?

Comment: Does `np.where()` help?

Comment: the `... = [...] += ..,`is bad syntax.

Comment: look a `sub_array`.  That's `example` without the outer rows and columns. `sub_array > 1` is the same size (n-2,n-2).  Look at the boolean array by itself.  The indexing has already been applied.

Comment: did you do?  `sub_array[sub_array > 1] += 1000`.  Did you look at `example` after?  It should be the same plus the outer rows and columns.. When doubt test each step.

Comment: All, Thank you for the comments. The sub_array is incorrect to what I am trying to accomplish. The sub array is taking the first and last list, which is correct, but is incorrectly adding 1000 to the values I am trying to change. I would like the 1000 to be added to values greater than 1, but not the first or last value greater than one in each list, as shown in the correct_example_array. It appears that starting the slice at [1:-1] doesn't take into account the 0s and instead slices even if there is no value to manipulate. I am going to review np.where as it seems promising. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it (not nice one maybe):

```
for i in range(example_array.shape[0]):
    if len(np.where(example_array[i]!=0)[0][1:-1])>0:
        example_array[i][np.where(example_array[i]!=0)[0][1:-1]] = example_array[i][example_array[i]!=0][1:-1]+1000
print(example_array)
```